# phalcon multilingual(by url) conflict with controller parameter

Tags: multilingual, phalcon

below is my router structure for multi lingual

```
$router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}+}/?', array(
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
));
$router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}+}/:controller', array(
  'controller' => 2
));
$router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}+}/:controller/:action', array(
  'controller' => 2,
  'action' => 3,
));
$router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}+}/:controller/:action/:params', array(
  'controller' => 2,
  'action' => 3,
  "params"     => 4,
));
```

and my controller

```
public function viewAction($slug=null)
{   
    if($slug==null){
        $slug=$this->auth->getId();
    }
    $parameters = array(
        "name" => $slug,
        "id" => $slug
    );

    //Casting Types
    $types = array(
        "name" => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
        "id" => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
    );
    $user = Users::findFirst(array(
        "id= :id: OR name = :name:",
        "bind" => $parameters,
        "bindTypes" => $types
    ));
    if (empty($user)) {
        return $this->dispatcher->forward(array(
            'controller' => 'error','action'     => 'show404'
        ));
    }
    $this->view->user = $user;
}

#0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->execute()
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->executePrepared(Object(PDOStatement), Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->query('SELECT "users"....', Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->_executeSelect(Array, Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\tuteer\app\controllers\UsersController.php(62): Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findFirst(Array)
#6 [internal function]: Vokuro\Controllers\UsersController->viewAction('zh')
#7 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\tuteer\public\index.php(27): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#9 {main}
```

if I use url `http://localhost/tuteer/zh/users/view/1`, it returns with correct response,
however if I use url `http://localhost/tuteer/zh/users/view`, it take zh as my default param and that equals to `http://localhost/tuteer/zh/users/view/zh`, is it something to do to router structure?

Comment: just a thought. try 'params'=>null for `/{language:[a-z]{2}+}/:controller/:action`

Comment: has tried before but worthless. Need to tell the router the what the param is before setting params

Comment: Here is the router parameter without using the parameters, `params => array('language'=>'zh')`, you should print out what the variable $slug   returns. Phalcon says to return the variable through `$this->dispatcher->getParam($paramName)`

Comment: when you use the parameter it the parameter returns `params=>array(0=>'1','language'=>'zh')`. So, I am guessing you can use `$this->dispatcher->getParam(0)`; if it doesn't exist, return `$this->auth->getId();`

Comment: Seems to be reasonable. I'll try this after get current bug fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
$di->set('router', function() {
    $router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

    $router->removeExtraSlashes(true);

    $router->add('/{lang:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action/:params', array(
        'controller' => 2,
        'action' => 3,
        'params' => 4,
    ));

    $router->add('/{lang:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action', array(
        'controller' => 2,
        'action' => 3,
    ));

    $router->add('/{lang:[a-z]{2}}/:controller', array(
        'controller' => 2,
        'action' => 'index',
    ));

    $router->add('/{lang:[a-z]{2}}', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));

    return $router;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround for the problem:

in the ControllerBase class

```
$lang = $langParam = $dispatcher->getParam('language');
if(!empty($langParam)){
        if(count($dispatcher->getParams())==1){
            $dispatcher->setParams(array());
        }
    }
```

however I think this method is not good enough because after that when you call dispatcher you have to set back your language param. Waiting for a better answer